# In React, how to pass an element as a Prop and Render without wrapping an element around it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I'm using React 16.2. I have a component to render a popup window which works like so:

```
<WindowPopOut
  trigger={<Button>Open Window PopUp</Button>}
  ....
/>
```

And then...

```
class WindowPopOut extends Component {
  ...
  render() { 
    const clonedTrigger = React.cloneElement(trigger, {
      onClick: this.handleTriggerClick,
    });
    return (
      <div>
        {clonedTrigger}
        ...
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is this renders in the DOM like so:

```
<div><Button>Open Window PopUp</Button></div>
```

How can I make `WindowPopOut` render without the DIV wrapping? So the component simply renders:

```
<Button>Open Window PopUp</Button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried wrapping with a `React.Fragment`?

```
return (
  <React.Fragment>
    {clonedTrigger}
    ...
  </React.Fragment>
);
```

[React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)

Comment: that's amazing. I didn't know <React.Fragment> existed. Thank you

Comment: Glad to help :) It was just added in v16.2. It's pretty cool. There is a shorter syntax as well ```<>...</>``` but support is spotty, It's discussed in the page I linked.